# 4 Column Full Width Link Blocks - Background Image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background, background-image

I am creating a 4 column section and wondering how I can put an image in the background of each block. Please see the snippet below and a screenshot of how I want the final product to look.

I am not sure how I can put an image in the background of each one. Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```html
<link href="http://impression.testcre8.co.uk/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://impression.testcre8.co.uk/assets/css/unify-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<ul class="nav nav-fill justify-content-center d-flex flex-wrap flex-lg-nowrap u-nav-v8-2" role="tablist"
              data-target="nav-8-2-primary-hor-center"
              data-tabs-mobile-type="slide-up-down"
              data-btn-classes="btn btn-md u-btn-primary btn-block">
  <li class="nav-item"> 
   <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#discuss" role="tab">
    <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Consult</h2>
    <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Understanding your brief, campaign goals &amp; vision.</p>
   </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> 
   <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#creativeConcept" role="tab">
    <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Design</h2>
    <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Creative concepts that bring your brief to life.</p>
   </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> 
   <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#modeling3D" role="tab">
    <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Create</h2>
    <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Fully in-house, quality-assured production.</p>
   </a> 
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"> 
   <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#happyClients" role="tab">
    <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Deliver</h2>
    <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Packing, dispatch &amp; on site installation management.</p>
   </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without image.

```css
.row {
   display: flex;
}
.block {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   color: white;
   width: 25%;
   height: 40px;
   padding-left: 30px;
   position: relative;
}
.block:not(:last-child):after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 100%;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 20px 0 20px 20px;
   z-index: 10;
}
.block:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: lightgray;
}
.block:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: gray;
}
.block:nth-child(even):after {
   border-color: transparent transparent transparent lightgray;
}
.block:nth-child(odd):after {
   border-color: transparent transparent transparent gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="block">1st</div>
   <div class="block">2nd</div>
   <div class="block">3rd</div>
   <div class="block">4th</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Jax-p I have got it to work without the images I am just wondering if the images are possible. Thanks!